# Cassandra concurrent row updates

Tags: cassandra, fwrite

How does Cassandra guarantee that columns are sorted for multiple concurrent column insert to a wide row? As far as i know, Cassandra doesn’t have a row lock.

Answer (score 1):

In Cassandra, a write is atomic at the row-level, meaning inserting or updating columns in a row is treated as one write operation.

Cassandra does not support transactions in the sense of bundling multiple row updates into one all-or-nothing operation. It is possible in Cassandra to have a write operation report a failure to the client, but actually persist the write to a replica.

Take into account that inserting is actually most of the time an in memory operation so keeping a single partition (row) sorted and inserting to it is relatively straight forward and is done at "redis like" speeds.

Cassandra uses timestamps to determine the most recent update to a column if there are multiple of them at the same time.

For operations happening in memory the old entry is then simply ignored.

The timestamp is provided by the client application or is set at the coordinator node. The latest timestamp always wins when requesting data, so if multiple client sessions update the same columns in a row concurrently, the most recent update is the one that will eventually persist.

If you are interested you can take a look under the hood:

https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/b02dec3da539d181544cfb0288102d6073f36264/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/Memtable.java#L262

Comment: It is worth to mention that row level isolation is available since Cassandra 1.1 (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-2893), more here http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/row-level-isolation